# Scraping: obtaining repeated list

Tags: python, list, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

I'm scraping with Selenium and Python two links from Kayak and I'm having problems with the output. I'd like to obtain a series of lists like this:

```
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m']
[...]
```

Instead I obtain the following oputput, with a repetition of each list in the following list:

```
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:30 – 15:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:30 – 15:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '10:20 – 12:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:30 – 15:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '10:20 – 12:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:30 – 15:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '10:20 – 12:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:30 – 15:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:30 – 15:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '10:20 – 12:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:30 – 15:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '10:20 – 12:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:30 – 15:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '10:20 – 12:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:30 – 15:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '10:20 – 12:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '14:45 – 16:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '22:20 – 23:55\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '16:35 – 18:05\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:30 – 15:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '10:20 – 12:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:30 – 15:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '10:20 – 12:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n7:00 – 8:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 30m', '14:45 – 16:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:30 – 15:00\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 30m\n9:20 – 11:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n10:50 – 12:30\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n10:50 – 12:30\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n10:50 – 12:30\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n10:50 – 12:30\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n10:50 – 12:30\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:00 – 14:45\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 45m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 17:25\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n10:50 – 12:30\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n10:50 – 12:30\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:00 – 14:45\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 45m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '13:00 – 14:45\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 45m\n14:55 – 16:35\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
```

This is my code, I can't understand where it's wrong.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
list_link = ['https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-02/2021-09-03/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0', 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-PMI/2021-09-02/2021-09-03/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0']
    
    wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options = chrome_options)
    wd.maximize_window()
    wd.implicitly_wait(50)
    wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 20)
    
    for link in list_link:
      wd.get(link)
      try:
          wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Accetta']"))).click()
      except:
          pass
    
      try:
          wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
      except:
          pass
    
      detail_flights = []
      j = 0
      lngth = len(wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo"))
      for i in range(lngth):
          try:
              if len(wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo")) > 0:
                  elements = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo")
                  wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elements[j])
                  j = j + 1
                  detail_flights.append(elements[j].get_attribute('innerText'))
    
                  print(detail_flights)
              else:
                  print('Nothing more to scrape')
          except:
              pass
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you have and this the output it creates?

Comment: Yes, in the output I obtain more lists, I put the first three just for example

Comment: I've edited the output, thank's!

Comment: Please include your import statements.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting that result is because you're adding each element to the list, and then printing the entire list every iteration.

To get the output you describe, you could print the inner text wrapped in a list for each iteration, for example by replacing `print(detail_flights)` with `print([elements[j].get_attribute('innerText')])`.

If what you want is a list of all the flights, then you've already got that in detail_flights. If you want a list of lists containing only the flights, then you want to wrap the inner text in a list before adding it to detail_flights.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using `.mainInfo` as a `css_selector`, and then using `innerText` which will print the entire inner text of `mainInfo`.

First URL has `16 links`, second has `10 links`. so in total it should `print 26`, cause you are **appending** everything to the `detail_flights`.

See below I have tried to explicitly retrieved prices : -

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
wd.maximize_window()
wd.implicitly_wait(50)
#driver.get('https://outlook.office.com/mail/')
wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 20)

list_link = ['https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-02/2021-09-03/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0', 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-PMI/2021-09-02/2021-09-03/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0']

for link in list_link:
    wd.get(link)
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Accetta']"))).click()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
    except:
        pass

    detail_flights = []
    j = 0
    k = 1
    price_list = []
    lngth = len(wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo"))
    for i in range(lngth):
        try:
            if len(wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo")) > 0:
                elements = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo")
                wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elements[j])
                j = j + 1
                detail_flights.append(elements[j].get_attribute('innerText'))
                price = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, f"(//span[@class='price-text'])[{k}]").text
                k = k  + 1
                price_list.append(price)
                print(detail_flights)
            else:
                print('Nothing more to scrape')
        except:
            pass

print(price_list)
```

**Output :**

```
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 –  
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['21:25 – 23:05\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n6:20 – 8:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '21:25 – 
['18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m']
['18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 
['18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 
['18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 
['18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 
['18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 
['18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 
['18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 
['18:30 – 20:10\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n22:00 – 23:40\nPMI Palma di Maiorca\n‐\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\ndiretto\n1h 40m', '15:45 – 
['52 €', '52 €', '52 €', '56 €', '56 €', '82 €', '86 €', '94 €', '94 €']
```