# Scraping information from different links. Problem: saving only the information of the first link scraped

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am scraping information from a list of links from kayak.

My code works well when I try to scrape only the information about the flight (such as time, airport,...), but when I try to add the price of the flight my code saves only the first link scraped.

This is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pprint

list_link = ['https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0', 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-PAL/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0']

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options = chrome_options)
wd.maximize_window()
wd.implicitly_wait(50)
#driver.get("https://account.battle.net/creation/flow/creation-full")
wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 20)

detail_flights = []

for link in list_link:
    
    wd.get(link)
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Accetta']"))).click()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        if len(wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo")) > 0:
            elements = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo")
        if len(wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".price-text")) > 0:
            bookings = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".price-text")

            box_flight = ""
            data_partenza = ""
            data_ritorno = ""
            price = ""
            url = ""
            for element, booking in zip(elements, bookings):
                wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
                date = link.replace('https://www.kayak.it/flights/', '')
                data_partenza = date[8:18]
                data_ritorno = date[19:29]

                wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", booking)
                detail_flights.append({"box_flight": [element.get_attribute('innerText')],
                                       "data_partenza": data_partenza,
                                       "data_ritorno": data_ritorno, 
                                       "price": booking.get_attribute('innerText'),
                                       "url": link})
                
        else:
            print('Nothing more to scrape')
    except:
        pass

for flight in detail_flights:
    print(flight)
```

And this is my output - I also need to save and see the information about the link 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-PAL/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0':

```
{'box_flight': ['8:10 – 9:45\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n14:50 – 16:35\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 45m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '59\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['8:10 – 9:45\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n14:50 – 16:35\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 45m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '59\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['8:25 – 10:00\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n14:50 – 16:35\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 45m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '63\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['8:10 – 9:45\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n19:05 – 20:45\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 40m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '64\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['8:25 – 10:00\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n19:05 – 20:45\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 40m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '68\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['8:10 – 9:45\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n14:20 – 16:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 40m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '74\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['8:10 – 9:45\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n12:15 – 14:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 45m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '74\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['8:10 – 9:45\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n18:55 – 20:40\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 45m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '74\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['9:55 – 11:35\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:50 – 16:35\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 45m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '76\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['8:25 – 10:00\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n14:20 – 16:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 40m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '78\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['8:25 – 10:00\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n18:55 – 20:40\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 45m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '78\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['8:25 – 10:00\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n12:15 – 14:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 45m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '78\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['8:10 – 9:45\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:45 – 9:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 45m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '80\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['9:55 – 11:35\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n19:05 – 20:45\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nLIN Aeroporto Milano Linate\ndiretto\n1h 40m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '81\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['8:25 – 10:00\nBGY Bergamo Orio al Serio\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 35m\n7:45 – 9:30\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 45m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '84\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
    {'box_flight': ['9:55 – 11:35\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\n‐\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\ndiretto\n1h 40m\n14:20 – 16:00\nBCN Barcellona-El Prat\n‐\nMXP Aeroporto Malpensa\ndiretto\n1h 40m'], 'data_partenza': '2021-09-05', 'data_ritorno': '2021-09-06', 'price': '91\xa0€', 'url': 'https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-BCN/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight__a&fs=stops=0'}
```

Comment: This was answered yesterday, wasn't it ? I think this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69020284/scraping-obtaining-repeated-list

Comment: It's a bit different question! Now I'm able to scrape correctly the "box_flight" of all the links, but I have the same problems of yesterday with the prices. There is the problem only when I add the prices

Comment: have a look, I have scraped prices as well, you would see the output with prices.

Comment: Yes, I've seen your code, thank you. But it gives me errors half of the times that I try to run it, I don't know why. This one that I posted doesn't give me problems. So I'd like to adapt this. I'm a beginner!!!

Comment: The second URL https://www.kayak.it/flights/MIL-PAL/2021-09-05/2021-09-06/?sort=bestflight_a&fs=stops=0 does not show any data

Answer (score 0):

The second `URL` that you have shared in `list_link` does not work at my end, so I could test it fully, but I do see issue with

```
 if len(wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".price-text")) > 0:
 bookings = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".price-text")
```

which is they are presenting 113 web elements where as `.mainInfo` only represent 16 of them. and in loop you have mentioned both of them in range.

```
for element, booking in zip(elements, bookings)
```

Changes that I have made is to replace the `css` with `xpath`, that represent only 16 prices not 113 or something like this.

```
try:
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo")) > 0:
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mainInfo")
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mainInfo']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::span[@class='price-text']")) > 0:
        bookings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mainInfo']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::span[@class='price-text']")
```